# Difference in size avaialbe in encrypted volume

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, file-system

I was making a volume with trucrypt and I set the size to be 12MB. I tried copying 10 files totalling 7.13MB (on Disk) but got an error saying I did not have enough space. Why is this? Is it because I'm copying from an NTFS format to FAT?

Comment: How about looking how big your usable space is? Other than that, 12MB is tiny. Each FS reserves space for metadata, independent of Truecrypt etc.

Comment: @deviantfan not sure I'm following. There's GBs worth of space on the physical hard drive.

Comment: If you´re using only 12MB for your volume (for your data + metadata together), why does the rest of the hard drive matter?

Comment: @deviantfan I thought that was your question, I have no clue what you're saying/asking.

Comment: I think you don´t understand what a volume is. If you have a Truecrypt volume of size X (or any partition of size X), it´s limited to size X and not a single byte more. In this limited area, not only your files, but some amount of file system support data has to fit in. Modern FS aren´t designed to be used on such tiny areas, eg. BTRFS wants *at least* 1GB for itself, even if you have not a single own file. FAT32 is not so greedy, but 12MB is still a problem. ... If you want to have a truecrypt are in your HDD which should hold 12MB files now, but could have more, make a much bigger volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Setting the size to 12 MB" doesn't tell much.

Some file systems do not scale well downwards. [FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) will reserve space for directory structures and file allocation tables, which will give you an [overhead](http://hjohn.home.xs4all.nl/SFS/spaceeff.htm) of unuseable space. The actual space left for storing files will be the volume size *minus* that overhead.

After creating the volume, open it (it will be empty) and check what the **available** size actually is.

Even so, differences in allocation block size may mean that you cannot store what on disk A are 8 megabytes onto disk B even if you have 8 megabytes free there (the "File size (on disk)" is what matters here). After each file copy, verify how much the available space has shrunk.